# Hash and the Numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, numbers, responsive-design

I have a gallery in jQuery Elastislide.

Each pictures of the gallery has a corresponding Hash.

For example : *www.example.com/gallery.html#4/title_of_the_picture*

So, when I reload the fourth image, the page loads the fourth image.

But when I reload without the number before the title in the Hash, picture doesn't load.

*www.example.com/gallery.html#title_of_the_picture*

Can I delete this number ? If I can, what is the right code in Jquery to use ?

jQuery Code :

```
Gallery = (function() {
    // index of the current item        
    var imageIndex = 0;
    if (window.location.hash) {
        var imageIndexStr = window.location.hash.replace('#', ''); // remove #
        imageIndex = parseInt(imageIndexStr, 0); // convert to int
    }

    var current = imageIndex;
    // mode : carousel || fullview
    mode = 'carousel',
    // control if one image is being loaded
    anim = false, init = function() {
        // (not necessary) preloading the images here...
        $items.add('<img src="ajax-loader.gif"/><img src="black.png"/>').imagesLoaded(function() {
            // add options
            _addViewModes();
            // add large image wrapper
            _addImageWrapper();
            // show first image
            _showImage($items.eq(current));
        });
    }
}​
```

Comment: there is no close brackets for your `init = function() {` and `Gallery = (function() {` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines of code:

```
var imageIndexStr = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
imageIndex = parseInt(imageIndexStr, 0); // convert to int
```

are going to try to convert the first char of the hash to an int, but if the first char is not a valid int (as would be the case if you removed the 4, like you are saying), then the JavaScript will error at that point and go no further.

Also - 0 does not seem to be a valid option for `parseInt()`, according to the documentation.

**EDIT :** Replaced link to W3Schools

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: the [real documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for anyone interested. [w3schools is not documentation](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: @jbabey i like w3schools... especially the tests... Javascript: screw scope, hoisting or closures as long as you know how to write comments :-D

Comment: Thanks, I find the solution, I just have to delete the line : `imageIndex = parseInt(imageIndexStr, 0); // convert to int`

Comment: Thanks for the documentation pointer ... I know w3schools is frowned upon